# influxDB | get elapsed time between last and first points

Tags: influxdb, elapsed

How to get difference between the first point in measurement and the last?

Example:

```
name: m1
time                ID ms
----                -- --
1573826041643021709 1  195
1573826041914872651 2  97
1573826042124354048 3  52
1573826042313151871 4  34
1573826042491637063 5  30
```

I need to get diff between `1573826041643021709` and `1573826042491637063`

`select sum(elapsed) from (select elapsed(ms) from m1)` shows me expected result, but the way looks complicated and it seems something easier and more elegant should be.

Comment: Additional info:in other words I want to get difference between start and end time. According to example above: ```1573826042491637063 - 1573826041643021709```.

Answer (score 1):

Find [first](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/functions/#first) and [last](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/functions/#last)  point in measurement for the field 'ms' and calculate the difference between them.

```
 select first(ms) - last(ms) from m1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i've got the following error while trying to perform this request:
```ERR: error parsing query: found ;, expected ) at line 1, char 53```

Comment: the first variant was closer to my task. I need tp get diff in time. It means ```1573826042491637063 - 1573826041643021709``` according to example above. Not ``195 - 30```